# What is the maximum length of a sql in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Now I will exec a long long long sql in ClickHouse,

```
ALTER table a MODIFY
TTL toDate(recordTimestamp) + INTERVAL 180 DAY DELETE WHERE tenant='A',
    toDate(recordTimestamp) + INTERVAL 150 DAY DELETE WHERE tenant='B',
    toDate(recordTimestamp) + INTERVAL 190 DAY DELETE WHERE tenant='C',
...
...
```

Maybe there are 1,000 tenants; So the sql will be too long, I'm not sure if CK can work properly.
Or is there any way for CK to support?

Comment: You can put expiration date into a dedicated column and fill it during insert. Then TTL expression will be `TTL expiration_date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the default sql size is 256 KiB.

but can be changed by setting [`max_query_size`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-max_query_size).

So it seems it actually depends on your RAM:

> The maximum part of a query that can be taken to RAM for parsing with the SQL parser.

Comment: So how to estimate the approximate memory occupied by SQL?

Comment: I believe you can use e.g. https://mothereff.in/byte-counter to count string bytes. So `select 1` will pass `max_query_size=8` but not `max_query_size=7`